# Laravel 4.2 change local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, localization

I am updating a site that was built using laravel 4.2.
I am adding multiple content languages and i ran into a problem with changing the 
local smoothly.

I wish every page to have the option to have a `/local` segment (`/en`, `/de` or `/hr`) appended to its URL but would dissapear.

The scenario that i am aiming at is to check if the url has a `/local` segment on its end and if it does just set the local in the `Session` and reload the page without the `/local` segment at the end.

There are similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559421/t-can-not-switch-language-in-laravel4), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482803/laravel-application-language-change) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273956/set-locale-on-the-fly-in-laravel4), but nothing that would give the visitor the option to change the language on any page and still let him stay on the site without changing the URL.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far (routes file and anything else relevant).

Comment: I just made a possible solution for this. I'll post it in a few minutes

Comment: I didn't put any code samples because they are the same as the default ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution turned out to work for me.
I think that there's room for improvement but it works fine.

The benefit of this solution compared to other similar ones is that the localisation is made for every link without modifying the `routes.php` and 
it doesn't reload he site to the homepage after changing the language.

My filter.php:

```
// filter.php

App::before(function($request)
{
    // Setting the locale
    $segments = $request->segments();
    $locale = "";
    $index = 0;
    foreach($segments as $segment){
        $index++;
        $locale = $segment;
    }

    // Set the local in Session if it's supported
    if ( $index > 0 && array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
        Session::put('locale', $locale);
        $segments = array_slice($segments,0, $index-1);
        // Reload the site without the ending /language part
        return Redirect::to(implode('/', $segments));
    }
    if(!Session::has('locale'))
    {
        Session::put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage( Config::get('app.languages')));
    }

    App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));

});
```

And this is my app.php:

```
//app.php
...
    'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'hr' => 'Hrvatski'],

    'languages' => ['en', 'hr'],
...
```